# Редактор кода Брекетс

Tags: php, xampp

Брекетс выдаёт замечание-Php runtime not found install the php7runtime and update  "executablepath" in php preferences appropriately this enablesphp-related tooling such as Code Hints  paramete Hints and more.  Как устранить?

Comment: Прямо в тексте замечания написано как устранить, какое слово вам непонятно?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел на просторах сети [оригинал](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/14716)

Он просто сообщает пользователю, что функции PHP не будут работать, если мы не сможем найти исполняемый файл php7.

Идём в Debug > Open Preferences File

Копируем все php настройки из defaultPreferences.json в brackets.json

Удаляем все комментарии, т.к. brackets.json не поддерживет комментарии. Это важно.

Замените настройки по умолчанию вашими собственными настройками. В случае каких-либо проблем с производительностью попробуйте увеличить ограничение памяти по умолчанию в соответствии с вашими потребностями.

Также путь в Win должен иметь \\ вместо /, ваш пример должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
"php": {
        "enablePhpTooling": true,
    "executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
    "memoryLimit": "4095M",
    "validateOnType": "false"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Хочу дополнить [Богдана Соловьева](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/271357/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2)...
Я лично ставил php [отсюда](https://www.php.net/downloads.php).

Лично у меня были проблемы с настройками, так как brackets даже свои стандартные настройки не понимал. В конечном итоге у меня получились вот такие настройки:

```
{
    "brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": true,
    "brackets-eslint.useLocalESLint": false,
    "fonts.fontSize": "12px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
    "php": {
        "enablePhpTooling": true,
        "executablePath": "C:\\PHP\\php.exe",
        "memoryLimit": "4095M",
        "validateOnType": "false"
    },
    "themes.theme": "dark-theme"
}
```